# CLOUDFLARE - mail setup

Tags: email, cloudflare

I have used Cloudflare for quite a while, but recently, I have bought a mail server with my domain.

I am unsure of how to "root the traffic" through cloudflare - because at the moment, I am unable to receive mail, but I can SEND mail.

I know I need to use MX Records, but I do not know how to get it working.

These are the settings for my mail serve:

```
Mail Server Username: help@domain.im
Incoming Mail Server: mail.domain.im
Incoming Mail Server: (SSL) mail.au.syrahost.com
Outgoing Mail Server: mail.domain.im (server requires authentication) port 25
Outgoing Mail Server: (SSL) mail.au.syrahost.com (server requires authentication) port 25
Supported Incoming Mail Protocols: POP3, POP3S (SSL/TLS), IMAP, IMAPS (SSL/TLS)
Supported Outgoing Mail Protocols: SMTP, SMTPS (SSL/TLS)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry if I have not explained enough!

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not SO

Comment: Do you have a "mail" name setup (Type A) in your DNS settings on CloudFlare? It should point to the same IP address (or to the IP of your mail server) and be set to bypass CloudFlare.

Comment: is that all I would need?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you have been using Cloudflare with your website and you are now wondering how to setup your new mail server on Cloudflare.

The mail details you give are for configuring an email client, but what you need are the MX details which are used to specify how to route email for your domain.

To find out MX details start by asking whoever is supplying your mail server.

They typically look something like:
MX priority 10 domain-x
MX priority 20 doman-y
.....
domain-x and domain-y may or may not be the same as your actual website domain.

Once you have the MX details, login to Cloudflare, click the settings icon for the domain and choose DNS settings. Add details of your new MX records and check if there may be outdated MX records there which you need to delete.

Good luck!